# Почему сброс эффекта из предыдущего компонента происходит позже начала рендера нового

Tags: reactjs, react-hook

Имею крайне простую структуру из компонента контейнера и двух вложенных компонентов, которые показываются по условию внутри контейнера.

Сам контейнер.

```
function List() {
    const [isListVisible, setIsListVisible] = useState<boolean>(false);

    console.log('List render start', isListVisible);

    const toggle = () => {
        setIsListVisible(!isListVisible);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            { isListVisible && <Item /> }

            { !isListVisible && <AltItem /> }

            <button onClick={toggle}>Toggle</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

И два вложенных (полностью одинаковые, только названия разные).

```
export const Item = () => {
    console.log('Item render start');

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Item effect start');

        return () => {
            console.log('Item effect cleanup');
        }
    },[]);

    return (
        <div>Item</div>
    );
}

export const AltItem = () => {
    console.log('AltItem render start');

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(' AltItem effect start');

        return () => {
            console.log(' AltItem effect cleanup');
        }
    },[]);

    return (
        <div>AltItem</div>
    );
}
```

Нажимая на кнопку Toggle мы размонтируем один компонент и монтируем другой. И в консоли лог следующего содержания :

```
List render start false
AltItem render start
Item effect cleanup
AltItem effect start
```

Т.е. логично предположить, что если isListVisible в значении fasle, то сначала должен размонтироваться Item и сработать сброс его эффекта, а после этого на это место смонтироваться AltItem.
Но судя по логу происходит наоборот. Сначала начинает рендериться AltItem и только после этого срабатывает сброс эффекта Item.

Иначе говоря - почему лог вот такой

```
List render start false
AltItem render start
Item effect cleanup
AltItem effect start
```

а не вот такой -

```
List render start false
Item effect cleanup
AltItem render start
AltItem effect start
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Потому что запись render у тебя выводится не при обновлении dom, а при вызове функции. До того, как она вызвана, невозможно определить, остался компонент на месте или нет, а значит до неё вызывать очистку нельзя. По крайней мере, если считать, что сначала формируется виртуальный dom, а потом он сопоставляется с предыдущим, а это вроде реакт гарантирует.

Comment: Частично мысль уловил. Но по-прежнему не понимаю почему лог из сброса эффекта именно там где он находится. Т.е. выходит что первый рендер AltItem происходит  как бы параллельно с выполнением сброса эффекта из Item?